# Bean loses its 'supplies Class' when deploying with cobertura / instrumented code

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, javabeans, instrumentation, cobertura

Under normal startup of my application checking the server log shows that when it is time for a particular bean to be deployed, it shows something along the lines of:

```
installing bean: ...

with dependencies: 
and demands:
  ...
and supplies:  
  jndi:My_EAR/My_Class/remote   
  Class:my.package.my.class  
  jndi:My_EAR/My_Class/local-my.package.my.class
```

However, if I deploy the same bean with all of the classes being instrumented by cobertura, it no longer 'supplies' the "Class:" entry, which seemingly stops me being able to inject the class without referencing it explicitly by JNDI name.

Is this intentional behaviour? Is there a way to force it to still supply the Class entry? It's a large codebase with a heavily used class so I'd rather not have to update all injection references if I can get away with it.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but could you share why you want to deploy the instrumented code? I've never done something like this, but I can see that it might have a use case or two (detect dead code?)

Comment: Pretty much, I have JUnit tests set up that are testing how things are acting within the container at the component level, I'd like to be able to see the coverage of said components if possible.